# how to submit dynamic table with html post

Tags: html, django, post

I have a html table which basically derived from my django model

```html
<form action="{% url 'checkout' %}" method="POST">
    <table id="table" class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">#</th>
          <th scope="col">Item</th>
          <th scope="col">Quntity</th>
          <th scope="col">Price</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for item in cartitems %}
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">{{ forloop.counter }}</th>
          <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
          <td data-count="1" id="counter_{{ forloop.counter }}">
            <button onclick="minus({{ forloop.counter }})" id="minusButton" data-count="1"
              class="btn btn-default btn-xs">
              <i class="fas fa-minus mr-2"></i>
            </button>
            1
            <button onclick="plus({{ forloop.counter }})" id="plusButton" data-count="1" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">
              <i class="fas fa-plus ml-2"></i>
            </button>
          </td>
          <td data-price="{{ item.price }}" id="counter_{{ forloop.counter }}">
            {{ item.price }}
          </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <td>Total Price</td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td id='totalPrice'></td>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
</div>
<div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Proceed To Checkout</button>
</div>
</form>
```

my quantity field in table comes from user so I want to post all data from table to django, Pls let me know if there is any easy way to do that.
right now my form doesnt do anything.

I know you can post quatity field through ajax but I do not want that because user might also remove some of the items from the cart

Comment: You need the variable you are modifying with your plus and minus buttons to be an input field so it is sent back to Django with the form

Comment: How should I pass value from my `td` tag to input field

Comment: Put the input field inside the td tag

Comment: Why is this so hard in html like no one in the world never needed to post a table before...